# Whenever Send Email add case number in Email subject and (Subject like Case'Subject [case number] ) Thanks in advance for your help!

Tags: deployment

Case'Subject [case number] )
subject : Application
Case number : 0005274

should be - Application [0005274]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever Send Email add case number in Email subject and (Subject like Case'Subject [case number] )
Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Go to Setup--> Quick Find Box --> Classic Email template --> Select Email template --> Edit -->Available Merge Fields -->case ->case subject

[image]

Thanks
Ajay Dubedi

Answer (score 0):

You do that in the 'Case' actions.
Look for the 'Send email' action, edit the default 'subject' with any fields you want.
Than use that action as the 'Send email'.